# LocalDateTime from Joda Time ISO 8601 formating with no timezone information

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jodatime

I'm working on Rest API in Spring Boot and we are using fantastic library Joda Time. Since my server is configured to work in UTC timezone there is no need to use in whole application `DateTime` which have `DateTimeZone` information in it. We prefer to use `LocalDateTime` for storing all dates in system.

Now the question is about printing `LocalDateTime` in IOS 8601 format. Take a look at the code below:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // server timezone
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime(); // yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ
LocalDateTime createdAtLocalDateTime =  LocalDateTime.now();
DateTime createdAtDateTime =  user.getCreatedAt().toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
logger.info("DT: {}", fmt.print(createdAtDateTime));
logger.info("LDT: {}", fmt.print(createdAtLocalDateTime));
```

This outputs such results:

```
DT: 2019-03-20T20:19:19.691Z
LDT: 2019-03-20T20:37:00.642
```

So there is no `Z` at the end when serializing `LocalDateTime` but there is a `Z` when we are serializing `DateTime` in UTC time zone.

**Now the question**: How I can configure formatter to output this TimeZone information at the end (this `Z` letter) during serializing `LocalDateTime` instances. I know it is always in UTC but one of our consuming libraries are expecting this timezone information and we can not change the code in it unfortunately.

**Better question**: How to configure Jackson `ObjectMapper` to serialize `LocalDateTime` into json with this `Z` information at the end?

Adding to the formatter `fmt.withZoneUTC()` does not work.

Comment: Write a custom serialiser / deserialiser that appends / removes the Z to/from the String. And have a look at the Instant class which may be closer aligned to your needs

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Instant is quiet good. It works for described scenario but when it is stored to MongoDb it is stored like this: { "iMillis" : NumberLong(1553117383722) }. We also want to store informations in database in IOS 8601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append a text literal to your formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime())
        .appendLiteral('Z')
        .toFormatter();
```

Comment: Do you think it will leave Z after serialization of LocalDateTime object? @shmosel

Comment: @MS90 Absolutely.

Comment: This is great answer. I can assume that `Z` is always at the end because server is always working in UTC. Thank You. It seems that `Instant` which also does not have TimeZone information is serialized with `Z` at the end so I don't understand why `LocalDateTime` does not contain it. This is not consistent and looks like a bug.

Comment: @MarcinKapusta It's not a bug. LocalDateTime doesn't have a time zone, so it doesn't make sense to include `Z`.

Comment: But `Instant` also does not have time zone and `Z` is presented at the end during serializing :)

Comment: There's no way to print an instant without some arbitrary offset or time zone. They chose to print it in UTC>

Comment: @MarcinKapusta Instant does have a timezone, it's UTC (indicated with the letter "Z"). This is implied because Instant counts milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (which is in UTC timezone)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt That's an implementation detail. To quote the [docs](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Instant.html): *An `Instant` should be used to represent a point in time irrespective of any other factor, such as chronology or time zone.*

Comment: @shmosel Ah sorry. All the while I thought this was about java.time (in which Instant is defined as UTC by the docs).  They're very similar but not the same :-)